# Bluetooth audio device connected and shows as audio device but not able to play sound

Tags: linux, debian, kde

I am using Debian with KDE Plasma, pulseaudio and bluedevil. All the default packages. I am able to connect to an audio device through bluetooth but I have tried everything on the internet but still it doesn't show up as an output device anywhere. Not even in pavucontrol.

I am kind of new to Linux so if you do want some additional information from my side, I would like to have the command as well to get that information, for lets say logs or something...

Answer (score 0):

Try `tail -f /var/log/messages` and watch when you connect and disconnect. That should tell  you what to do. One thing for sure is   reset the device.

Comment: command gives: 
tail: cannot open '/var/log/messages' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining

Comment: `cd /var/log && sudo tail -f messages`

Comment: Gives the same error...